# Select specific json value from cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a Google Sheet, I have information in a json (or json-like?) format as e.g.:

`[{"value":"+44 1234 98715963","isPrimary":true},{"value":"+44 7784 9122","isPrimary":false}]`

What I am trying to achieve (via formula and/or script) is the following: Show the value where the flag "isPrimary" equals true in a new cell.
In the above example that would be `+44 1234 98715963`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to bluntly remove the value b/w `value:` & `isPrimary:true` but definitely not looking for some exact pattern inside, you may give a shot at:

```
=index(if(len(A2:A),regexextract(substitute(A2:A,"""",""),":([^:]*),isPrimary:true"),))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,".*""(\+\d+ \d+ \d+)"",""isPrimary"":true")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: It works for some values, but for most I get the following error: "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value ".*"(\+\d+ \d+ \d+)","isPrimary":true" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value"
Would you be able to explain the formula a little so I know where adjustments might be needed?

Comment: Sure. But -to understand it better- first share an example where formula doesn't work.

Comment: E.g. [{"value":"+43 (0)234 926 32-954  ","isPrimary":true},{"value":"+43 (262) 77 32 ","isPrimary":false}]

Comment: `\d+` means any one or more digits. Unfortunately your data does not follow a single pattern. The formula works for a pattern like *"+123 3456 45637"*. In your second example you have  *"+43 (0)234 926 32-954"*     in 5 groups with parenthesis and dash. **You have to have a consistent pattern**. You need to manually fix those. If your data is inconsistent no formula will work :(

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The "pattern" I see is the data in question is a string in quotation marks and with a clear identifier before and after, so I assumed it shouldn't be too complicated. Maybe I need to parse the values from the json into separate fields first?

Comment: Just fix the inconsistent ones. Needs some manual work and maybe an extra formula or two.